# How do I renew my Let's Encrypt TLS certificate on AWS Lightsail Wordpress instance?

Tags: https, certificate, lets-encrypt, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I setup a wordpress instance on AWS Lightsail and enabled HTTPS using bncert-tool as per [this](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-enabling-https-on-wordpress) guide. Today I received an urgent email from Let's Encrypt asking to renew my TLS certificate(s) that were issued from Let's Encrypt using the TLS-ALPN-01 validation method.

How do I renew the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your lightsail instance and run the following commands:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop

sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="EMAIL-ADDRESS" --domains="DOMAIN" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" renew --days 90

sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

In the preceding commands, replace EMAIL-ADDRESS and DOMAIN with the correct values.

You can use any of your working email addresses. Or, you can use the same email address that you used when you installed the certificate. You can retrieve the email you used when installing the certificate by running the following command:

```
sudo ls /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/accounts/acm*
```

You can confirm the domain name by running the following command:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --path /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt list
```

For more info, please refer to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lightsail-bitnami-renew-ssl-certificate/) documentation

Answer (score 1):

Now by default Bitnami `bncert-tool` renew the certificate automatically each month.
Source: [generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/)

Run the following command:

```bash
sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
```

If you encounter `Account [EMAIL ADDRESS] is not registered. Use 'run' to register a new account.`

Use this command to register a new account and create a new certificate:

```bash
sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="EMAIL-ADDRESS" --domains="DOMAIN" --domains="www.DOMAIN" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" run
```

Source: [letsencrypt community](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/about-lets-encrypt-renewal/145646)